# Как работает автообновление интерфейса Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Не получается организовать цикличное обновление интерфейса
Есть сервер, который при запуске должен выводить, например, уведомление о том, что он получил новое сообщение от клиента. Вот фрагмент кода.

```
def startServ(): # запускаем его отдельным потоком
    thread.start_new_thread(taskServer, ())

def taskServer():
    print("Server thread started")
    host = ""
    port = 50005
    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.bind((host, port))
    sock.listen(10)
    servStat.put("Ready") # Кидаем сообщение о запуске в очередь
    ...

servStat = queue.Queue() # сама очередь

def readServStatus(): # извлечение из очереди
    try:
        serverStatus = servStat.get(block=False)
    except queue.Empty:
        serverStatus = "Unknown"
    servLabel["text"] = serverStatus

# Сервер запускается из выпадающего меню и действительно работает

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    root = Tk()
    testLabel = Frame(root)
    testLabel.pack()
    servLabel = Label(testLabel, text="Server status")
    root.after(2000, readServStatus)
    servLabel.pack(side=RIGHT)
    root.mainloop()
```

На практике выводится надпись "Server status" и через пару секунд меняется на "Unknown". Больше она никак не реагирует на изменения состояния, не смотря на то, что mainloop() вроде как цикл.
Как ее заставить это делать?

Answer (score 1):

После установки новых параметров нужно обновить виджет методом `update`.

```
servLabel["text"] = serverStatus
servLabel.update()
```

Comment: Я пока испытываю своеобразный костыль. Псоле строки `servLabel = Label(testLabel, text="Server status")
` добавил запуск нового потока  `thread.start_new_thread(readServStatus, ())`, а в readServStatus() добавил цикл. И если в очереди что-то появляется, то он вставляет нужное значение. Пока работает. Сейчас попробую Ваш способ.